# Est-ce que "bon courage" est retournable?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation, politesse

Récemment, j'ai contacté un recruteur pour me renseigner sur des opportunités de stage dans son entreprise. Le recruteur à répondu en disant que les stages avaient déjà commencé, mais qu'il pourrait voir. Il a demandé que je lui envoie mon CV et a terminé en me  souhaitant bon courage. Je lui ai remis mon CV en le remerciant pour sa considération. J'ai fini ma réponse en lui souhaitant  bon courage également.

Néanmoins, un de mes amis m'a dit qu'il n'est pas adéquat de dire "bon courage" à un recruteur, ou une personne  "en position hiérarchique supérieure" (je connais pas de meilleure description) comme un professeur ou un directeur, etc. J'ai posé la même question à ChatGPT et il m'a aussi dit que ce n'était pas normal, mais j'ai tendance à avoir peu de confiance dans les réponses fournies par ce dernier.

Dans [linternaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/bon-courage/), la définition suivante est mentionnée:

> **Bon courage:** 
> Que l'on prononce pour soutenir une personne qui va s'exposer à des épreuves.

Évidemment, chaque personne passe chaque jour par des épreuves et des difficultés. Est ce que cela veut dire que l'expression "bon courage" est "retournable", dans le sens qu'il serait approprié de répondre "bon courage à vous également" lorsqu'on nous souhaite un bon courage?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147247/discussion-on-question-by-user45455674654-est-ce-que-bon-courage-est-retournab); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ton ami a eu raison. *Bon courage* sous-entend que la personne à qui on s'adresse est en train ou va traverser une période difficile ou délicate et rien ne permet de penser que c'est le cas du recruteur en question.

Ta réponse initiale (remerciements pour la considération de la demande) est la meilleure et elle était suffisante.

D'un autre côté, ce n'est pas bien grave d'avoir souhaité un bon courage à ce recruteur. Il risque seulement de se demander pourquoi tu lui as dit ça mais ça ne devrait pas risquer d'affecter tes chances d'obtenir un stage s'il y en a de disponibles.

PS: Tu as bien raison de te méfier des réponses de ChatGPT ! Elles sont parfois correctes ou passables mais il lui arrive aussi de dire des énormités avec beaucoup d'assurance...

Comment: L'originalité bienveillante et la spontanéité sont des atouts potentiels pour avoir son CV au sommet de la pile pour un stage dans lequel les relations humaines sont importantes… au poker des annonces d'embauches, le recruteur investit un RV… “Pour voir”

Comment: Suivant la façon dont l'entrevue s'est déroulée, je me méfierais quand même que "bon courage" ne soit pas perçu comme ironique - soit, dans un sens, parce que le candidat ne serait pas vraiment bon, soit dans l'autre sens, parce que le recruteur et le poste proposé ne seraient pas terribles... Ceci dit, si le recruteur cherche quelqu'un de pointu et a fait part de difficultés à pourvoir le poste, "bon courage" au recruteur pourrait être ce qu'il faut dire.

Comment: @Frank Oui, pourquoi pas dans un entretien d'embauche mais là, il s'agit d'une sollicitation de stage probablement faite par téléphone. Il n'y a pas (directement) de poste à pourvoir.

Comment: @jlliagre oui, tu as raison.